# How to create a Scapy packet from raw bytes

Tags: python, scapy

Using the python packet parsing/sniffing tool Scapy, I would like to create a packet from a raw byte-string.  While the details of my specific use-case are more realistic, the following example illustrates my problem and my present attempt:

```
# Get an example packet (we won't really have an offline file in production.)
pkt = sniff(offline="./example_packets/example_packets2.pcap")

# Convert it to raw bytes -- oddly __str__ does this.
raw_packet = str(pkt)

# Current, broken, attempt to construct a new packet from the same bytes as the old.
# In truth, there are easier ways to copy packets from existing Scapy packets, but
# we are really just using that offline packet as a convenient example.
new_packet = Packet(_pkt=raw_packet)

# Sadly, while this packet has the bytes internally, it no longer has the
# interpretations of the layers like the original packet did (such as saying that
# the packet is ARP and has these field values, etc.
print repr(new_packet)
```

How can I produce a `new_packet` from raw bytes that will look the same as if it were sniffed from a pcap file?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is no way for Scapy to guess the first layer of your packet, so you need to specify it.

You can do so by using the appropriate `Packet` subclass. For example, say your packet's first layer is Ethernet, use `Ether(raw_packet)` instead of `Packet(raw_packet)`.

Comment: If the `Ether` class is used, will Scapy be able to determine the other layers automatically?  It seems that the `sniff` function somehow figures out the other layers.

Comment: If by other layers you mean the layers on top of the Ethernet layer, the answer is yes, thanks to the `type` field.

Comment: Of course! That should've been obvious to me.  Thanks for the clarification.  (How else would routers know how to interpret the other layers if not for type information?)

Comment: Use `from scapy.layers.l2 import Ether` to get `Ether`. I got this by grepping through the installed library code.