# Scapy read packets from bytes

Tags: networking, scapy

I receive in real-time a list of raw packets (bytes) and I want to parse them into scapy without having to write and read them from a pcap.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27262291/how-to-create-a-scapy-packet-from-raw-bytes) the answer is to use Ether if the first layer is Ether, but what if not?

For example:

```py
>>> pkt.layers()
>>> [scapy.layers.inet6.IPv6, scapy.layers.inet.TCP]
>>> pkt.build()
>>> b'`\x00\x00\x00\x00(\x06@ \x01\x06\x18\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00Q\x99\xccp \x01\x06\x18\x00\x01\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x8c\x9b\x00Pj\xe7\x076\x00\x00\x00\x00\xa0\x02\x160)\x9c\x00\x00\x02\x04\x05\x8c\x04\x02\x08\n\x00\xdd\x1a9\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x03\x03\x02'
```

I can't use `Ether(pkt)` since `pkt` has no `Ether` layer.

But if I write the packet to a pcap file and read it again I can parse it.

```py
>>> wrpcap("/tmp/proof.pcap", pkt)
>>> pcap = rdpcap("/tmp/proof.pcap")                              
>>> type(pcap[0])
scapy.layers.inet6.IPv6
```

How could I parse packets like `wrpcap-rdpcap` without writing and reading files all time?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```py
pkt.__class__(bytes(pkt))
```

to re-build a packet regardless of its type.
It's very unclear what object `pkt` is in your example but I assumed it was a packet object.

For instance

```
pkt = Ether()/IP()
pkt.__class__(bytes(pkt))
```

If you're asking how to dissect bytes that you don't know the type of (without the datalink), the answer is: it's impossible.

Comment: Can you use an example? That doesn't work for me

Answer (score -1):

A way without using pcap files is using hexedit, e.g:

```
>>> from scapy.all import *
>>> data = b'`\x00\x00\x00\x00(\x06@ \x01\x06\x18\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00Q\x99\xccp \x01\x06\x18\x00\x01\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x8c\x9b\x00Pj\xe7\x076\x00\x00\x00\x00\xa0\x02\x160)\x9c\x00\x00\x02\x04\x05\x8c\x04\x02\x08\n\x00\xdd\x1a9\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x03\x03\x02'
>>> pkt = Packet(data)
>>> pkt.build()
b'`\x00\x00\x00\x00(\x06@ \x01\x06\x18\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00Q\x99\xccp \x01\x06\x18\x00\x01\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x8c\x9b\x00Pj\xe7\x076\x00\x00\x00\x00\xa0\x02\x160)\x9c\x00\x00\x02\x04\x05\x8c\x04\x02\x08\n\x00\xdd\x1a9\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x03\x03\x02'
>>> test = hexedit(pkt)
>>> type(test[0])
<class 'scapy.layers.l2.Dot3'>
```

It returns scapy.layers.l2.Dot3 in difference with scapy.layers.inet6.IPv6 because you are using binary data in your code.

```
>>> data = b'`\x00\x00\x00\x00(\x06@ \x01\x06\x18\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00Q\x99\xccp \x01\x06\x18\x00\x01\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x8c\x9b\x00Pj\xe7\x076\x00\x00\x00\x00\xa0\x02\x160)\x9c\x00\x00\x02\x04\x05\x8c\x04\x02\x08\n\x00\xdd\x1a9\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x03\x03\x02'
>>> pkt = Packet(data)
>>> pkt.build()
b'`\x00\x00\x00\x00(\x06@ \x01\x06\x18\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00Q\x99\xccp \x01\x06\x18\x00\x01\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x8c\x9b\x00Pj\xe7\x076\x00\x00\x00\x00\xa0\x02\x160)\x9c\x00\x00\x02\x04\x05\x8c\x04\x02\x08\n\x00\xdd\x1a9\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x03\x03\x02'
>>> wrpcap("/tmp/proof.pcap", pkt)
>>> pcap = rdpcap("/tmp/proof.pcap") 
>>> type(pcap[0])
<class 'scapy.layers.l2.Dot3'>
```

Comment: Ass you see, your method doesn't work.. You parsed it into Dot3 layer not IPv6

Comment: @manulqwerty, hexedit function works in the same way that rdpcap function. In this case it parsed into Dot3 in Wireshark too. It is because you wrote binary data as a string... I took your code example.

Comment: I get the packets in binary daya because I'm using pcapy as sniffer.

Now I'm parsing the packets to scapy using `Ether(pkt)` but if the first layer is not "Ether" it won't work.

You are using `Packet(pkt)` to parse it into SCAPY, but it doesn't work like that.

Comment: So, which is the difference between hexedit and wrpcap-rdpcap? I have run your code and obtain the same results for both.